# How to take several items from dictionary

Tags: python

Dictionary:

```
d = {'a':[2,3,4,5],
     'b':[1,2,3,4],
     'c':[5,6,7,8],
     'd':[4,2,7,1]}
```

I want to have `d_new` which containes only `b` and `c` items.

```
d_new = {'b':[1,2,3,4],
         'c':[5,6,7,8]}
```

**I want a scalable solution**

**EDIT**:

I also need a method to create a new dictionary by numbers of items:

```
d_new_from_0_to_2 = {'a':[2,3,4,5],
                     'b':[1,2,3,4]}
```

Comment: And I **want to you write some code**. I guess we're both going to be disappointed, today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a general way to pick particular keys (and their values) from a dict, you can do something like this:

```
d = {'a':[2,3,4,5],
     'b':[1,2,3,4],
     'c':[5,6,7,8],
     'd':[4,2,7,1]}

selected_keys = ['a','b']

new_d = { k: d[k] for k in selected_keys }
```

Gives:

```
{'a': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

I think that in Python 2.6 and earlier you would not be able to use a dict comprehension, so you would have to use:

```
new_d = dict((k,d[k]) for k in selected_keys)
```

Comment: Can you see an edit, please?

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav If you've got another question, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
new_d = dict(b=d.get('b'), c=d.get('c'))
```

Comment: I thought about it, but what if `b` is not there?

Comment: But what if i have 500 items and want to have 250 of them

Comment: Then just run a for/while loop and filter.

Comment: Pleas ask the original question for better understanding

Comment: The items you want are known in a list?

Comment: check the anwser of @khelwood. I believe is exactly what you want